# Match repeating pattern using single group in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the JS regex object, is it possible to match a repeating pattern using a single, or few groups?

For instance, taking the following as input:

```
#222<abc#321cba#123>#111
```

Would it be possible to match both "#321" and "#123" (but not #222 or #111, as they're outside the `/<.*?>/` group) using a regex similar to:

```
/<.*?(?:(#[0-9]+).*?)>/
```

(which currently only matches the first instance), when the number of matches in the input is unknown?

Comment: Did you mean `123` and `321`?  They are the reverse of each other.

Comment: The numbers were only selected so I had something to match. The actual numbers don't really mean anything.

Comment: RegEx engines can't capture an unknown amount of groups and captures need to be continuous (so 1:`#321` and 2:`#123` **or** 1:`#321cba#123`). You were close to *almost* accomplishing this, if you made your non-capturing group repeat it capture `#321` and then overwrite this capture with `#123`: [`<.*?(?:(#[0-9]+).*?)+>`](http://regex101.com/r/dM4qY1/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to loop over the inner pattern.
First use `/<(.*?)>/` to extract it:

```
var outerRegex = /<(.*?)>/;
var match = outerRegex.exec(input);
var innerPattern = match[1];
```

Next, iterate over the result:

```
var innerRegex = /#\d+/g;
while (match = innerRegex.exec(innerPattern))
{
    var result = match[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1, I don't see another way to do it. You can change the pattern to `<[^>]+>` to be more efficient *(and to avoid problems if there is no `>` in the string)*.